# A question about the Lebesgue integral of a function relative to the counting measure

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose X is a measurable space and $\mathit u$ is the counting measure on X. I want to prove that for any non-negative measurable functions $\mathit f$, $\int\mathit f=\sum\mathit f(x)$, where $\sum\mathit f(x)$ is defined to be the supremum of the set of all finite sums $\mathit f(x_1)+f(x_2)+...+f(x_n)$ and $\mathit x$ ranges over X. I have proved that if X is countable, then $\int\mathit f=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i)$. But I can't do this when X is uncountable.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If $A=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ is any finite subset of $X$ then $\int f \geq \int_A f=\sum_i \int_{\{x_i\}} f =\sum _i f(x_i)$. Hence $\int f \geq \sup \{\sum_{x\in A} f(x)\}$ where the supremum is over all finite subsets.  If $\sup \{\sum_{x\in A} f(x)\}=\infty$ this completes the proof. Suppose $\sup \{\sum_{x\in A} f(x)\}<\infty$. Then the set of points $x$ with $f(x)>\frac 1 n$ is a finite set for each $n$. Taking union of these sets we see that $f$ is $0$ except on a set which is at most countable. Now you can complete the proof since the proof is reduced to the case where we have a countable space.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only consider the definition of Lebesgue integral using simple functions.

Comment: If there are infinitely many points $x_1,x_2,..$ with $f(x_i) >\frac  1 n$ for each $i$ then $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} f(x_i) >\frac N n$ for each $N$ so $\sup \sum_{x \in A} f(x)=\infty$. @AsukaLangleySohryu